# Why I can't return a generic nullable value type and nullable reference type?

Tags: c#

I have a method that should return a nullable reference type or a nullable value type:

```
   private static T? FooValueOrReferenceType<T>(string input)
   { 
       return null;
       // the code above show this error 
       // Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be
       // a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.
   }
```

I don't understand why I cant return null, since I have enabled nullable value types in the project

I know that adding constraint `where T : struct, class` can resolve the problem, but I want to understand why.

I noticed that this method signature:

```
private static T? FooValueType<T>(string input) where T : struct
```

compiled to:

```
   private static Nullable<T> FooValueType<T>([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(1)] string input) where T : struct
```

and this:

```
private static T? FooReferenceType<T>(string input) where T : class
```

compiles to:

```
private static T FooReferenceType<T>(string input) where T : class
```

What's the reason behind all this?

There is some question similar to this one, but the answers are not clear for a noob like me.

Comment: _"since i have enabled nullable value types"_ - do you mean nullable reference types?

Comment: [Here is some discussion about this on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-11-25.md)

Comment: [And some further discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/3060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, nullability means two fundamentally different things for reference-types and value-types. For value-types, `T?` means `Nullable<T>` - a wrapper layer *around* a `T`, with some compiler voodoo - and for reference-types, `T?` means simply `T`, but with some additional compiler context (and attributes added, to convey that intent). There is simply no way *in IL* of expressing these two things at the same time, and `Nullable<T>` and `T` cannot be used interchangeably in IL (even if C# makes it look like you can). Ultimately, "you just can't, IL doesn't work that way".

Your two experiments into the `: class` and `: struct` show these two incompatible variants nicely.